# Custom minimizer based on Levenberg-Marquardt in scipy.optimize.basinhopping

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, data-fitting, levenberg-marquardt

I'm having troubles to minimize a complex non linear function in python. This function is actually the chiSquare of a fitting model used to fit experimental data. In order to get the global minimum, I'm using the basinhopping function in scipy. This function is a wrapper of the minimize() function that adds some perturbation to look for different local minima. Right now my problem is that it has troubles to find the local minima.

There are a bunch of solvers that can be used in minimize(), and since I'm using bounds I chose between 'L-BFGS-B', 'SLSQP' and 'TNC'. None of them really find local minima. Is there a method based on the popular Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm that can be use to minimize? Maybe this does not make sense otherwise it would be already implemented, but I can't understand why.

My original idea was actually to use the leastsqbound function(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/leastsqbound) that I know is very good at providing accurate covariance matrix despide the bounds, and include it in a larger algorithm that would look for global minima (like the basinhopping function). Do you know if something like this already exist?

Thanks a lot for you advices!

Answer (score 2):

Scipy has a Levenberg-Marquardt implementation: `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. It does not have the right return type to use with `minimize` (and therefore `basin_hopping`). However, it appears this could be remedied fairly straightforwardly.

Though I have not run it, this should do the trick:

```
def leastsq_for_minimize( *args, **kwargs ):
    results = leastsq( *args, **kwargs )
    optimize_results = scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult()
    # Some code here to correctly copy results to optimize results
    return optimize_results

scipy.optimize.basinhopping(
    # your arguments here
    minimizer_kwargs=dict(method=leastsq_for_minimize),
    )
```

- [minimize documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)
- [basinhopping documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping):
- [OptimizeResult documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html)

Comment: Thanks Andreus, but leastsq cannot be used as a method in minimize() or in basinhopping. So it does not really answer my problem.

Comment: Okay, after posting that big edit, I now see why my solution doesn't work. My only suggestion is to try and wrap `scipy.optimize.leastsq` in a function which matches the calling convention of custom `minimize` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had already tried that, but the minimize function does not want to take leastsq as valid method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: **"The method shall return an OptimizeResult object."** This is required for the minimize() routine. You could try writing a function which calls leastsq, and turns the result of leastsq into an OptimizeResult (from the documentation, it appears that leastsq returns enough information to partially or completely fill out that object). Then you could pass this function to minimize().